# Does passing reference to itself to constructor of base class causes undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

while implementing some design ideas I stumbled upon some strange behavior, which I cannot explain myself.

Take a look at the following example, which has been compiled with MSVC2010.

```
struct A
{
    void helloMe()
    {
        std::cout << "hej da!\n";
    }
};

struct B
{
    B(A& a): 
        m_a(a)
        {
            std::cout << "B got constructed!\n"; 
        }

A& m_a;
};

struct C : A, B 
{
    C() : 
        A(),
        B(*this)
        { std::cout << "C got constructed!\n";
        }
};

int _tmain() 
{

    C c;
    c.m_a.helloMe();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles error free, but when executing, the constructor of B is never called. That is, when trying to access `m_a`, I got an segfault. But when explicitly casting to have `*reinterpret_cast<A*>(this)`, the constructors are called as intended.

So why does the above example not work, but I need to explicitly cast? Is this a compiler dependent issue?

EDIT:

So with cast it would look like:

```
struct A
{
    void helloMe()
    {
        std::cout << "hej da!\n";
    }
};

struct B
{
    B(A& a): 
        m_a(a)
        {
            std::cout << "B got constructed!\n"; 
        }

A& m_a;
};

struct C : A, B 
{
    C() : 
        A(),
        B(*reinterpret_cast<A*>(this))
        { std::cout << "C got constructed!\n";
        }
};

int _tmain() 
{

    C c;
    c.m_a.helloMe();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you created a `C` object the `B` constructor *is* called. Can you show us code for how you would use: `*reinterpret_cast<B*>(this)`

Comment: Could you post code that compiles and demonstrates that the constructor of `B` isn't called? This is riddled with syntax errors, as well as the ambiguity over whether `*this` should be converted to `A&` for your constructor, or `B&` for the implicit copy constructor.

Comment: Pro tip: When posting questions, use `struct`, not `class`, and remove all the `public` noise. Then more people can see your actual design rather than a wall of boilerplate.

Comment: "This compiles error free" [Try again](http://ideone.com/XZPbaV).

Comment: Stop. Come back when you are prepared to post your _actual_ testcase, rather than taking iterative stabs in the dark. What you have at the moment isn't even syntactically valid.

Comment: Sorry about that, tried to reduce productive code, where it actually happened. Obviously reduced it too well :p. Above minimal example works and shows the symptoms, i.e. in the first case, the constructor of the base class is not called, while with cast, the base class' constructor is actually called.

Comment: Without the cast [it doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26ae4ec5767b1906) (rightfuly so). You should report this as compiler's bug.

Comment: @jrok It does compile. Just not with gcc.

Comment: In this minimal example it even works as intended, even though the constructor is not called. In my product code, it crashes with a seg fault. That's what I meant with undefined behavior.

Comment: In g++, there are still some changes needed, but it definitively doesn't compile because of ambiguity about calling either B(const B&) or B(A&), which seems reasonable because the cast removes the ambiguity.

Comment: @nos Right. But the standard says the call is ambiguous, so...

Comment: The one with `reinterpret_cast` is undefined. Which if any base class is at the same address as the derived is not standard. Try `static_cast` instead to make the operation explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jrok pointed out, this is a compiler error. The compiler does not recognize the ambiguous call of the copy constructor and the explicit one.
Further, a `static_cast<A*>` would have been the right choice there.

So indeed, the cast is necessary according to the standard and MSVC2010 lacks in standard conform behavior. It just calls the copy constructor without even considering the actually declared one. Thus segfaults may occur. You will notice the copy constructor call, when explicitly declaring the copy constructor private. Then MSVC2010 complains.

Thanks for your comments.